# Specific select/update sql commands not running

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with 2 columns "option" and "value". Both of them are varchar(50). option is set as primary.

I have this select command

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value, option FROM menu_theme WHERE option='menu_height'");
```

And I have this update command

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE menu_theme SET value='$_POST[value]' WHERE option='$_POST[command]'") or die($con->error);
```

Both of these commands break because of something wrong with the syntax near "option". I have no idea why.

- The connection to the database is fine.
- The UPDATE command is receiving the posted information fine.

This was an error I received when it tried to make the update command

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option='menu_height'' at line 1
```

Comment: Try putting option in backticks to escape it. Option is a keyword in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-6.html

Comment: Is there a difference between using backticks and using a single quote?

Comment: Yes, backticks are for escaping names, quotes are for string literals. When I'm saying put option in backticks I mean like `\`option\` = 'menu_height'`

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPTION` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) which needs to be enclosed in backticks.

I.e.:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value, `option` FROM menu_theme WHERE option='menu_height'");
```